# Client side load balancing with redis-py

Tags: python, redis, high-availability, fault-tolerance, redis-py

I have a redis setup with 1 master and 2 slaves on ElastiCache. Master failover is already handled, but I want to make sure:

- Reads are load-balanced across the three servers
- Writes only go to the master
- Should a read fail, we try again at another node

I'm having a tough time making this happen with redis-py:

1) It has support for connection pooling (and suggests we can support client-side sharding this way) but the documentation doesn't specify whether or not it'll retry on an error.

2) It doesn't provide a clear way to specify whether one type of connection is for reads and another is for writes... I suppose I could make two StrictRedis instances?

Any ideas on the best way to handle this? Looks like there are a few projects tackling this, but none of them have had commits in the past two years:

- https://github.com/salimane/rediscluster-py
- https://github.com/StartTheShift/jondis